# upload multiple epub/zip files on cloudinary [reactjs]

Tags: reactjs, zip, epub, cloudinary

when i try and upload epub file , i get respone
   {"error":{"message":"Unsupported ZIP file"}}
what am i doing wrong here:

```js
const formData=new FormData();
formData.append("resource_type", "auto");
formData.append("file", file);
formData.append("upload_preset", config.upload_preset);
formData.append("api_key", config.api_key);
formData.append("timestamp", (Date.now() /1000) |0);
 
await axios.post(cloudinaryUploadUrl, formData, {
headers: { "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",},
}).then(response => {
constdata=response.data;
gUrl=gUrl.concat([data.secure_url]);
})
```

update , i was using wrong url to upload raw files
 I was using link :
'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1//image/upload'
 instead of
'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1//raw/upload'

hence the issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the supported file types here- https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#image_format_support

Answer (score 0):

We are checking this issue with the team and will update you with any insights.